# Equation with two separate answers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, amsmath

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    2x^2+x &= 0 &\\
    x(2x+1) &= 0 &\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    x &= 0 & 2x+1 &=0\\
    & & 2x &=-1\\
    & & x &=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

I have one equation that I'm solving step by step. After using the zero-product property, the equation solution splits into two equations. I need the two equations to be aligned, but not with the first one (equal signs in first two lines not aligned with the second two lines). I still want the results and equation to be numbered as one equation (now the number is in a wrong place).

After all that I want the another result to be cancelled like `\cancel{x = 0}` and the other to be double-underlined as the final result `\underline{\underline{x=-1}}`.

Any suggestions how to complete this code?

Comment: Do you want 4 lines with a single number?

Comment: The second line might be wrong. I think it should be `x(2x+1)`. Correspondingly the right branch may be incorrect, too.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `forest` or `tikz-cd` to illustrate these things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={edge+={thick,-stealth},math content}
[{2x^2+x=0}
 [{x(2x+1)=0}
  [{x=0},tier=f
  ]
  [{2x+1=0}
   [{x=-\frac{1}{2}},tier=f]
  ]
 ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={Leftrightarrow},column sep=0em]
 &  2x^2+x=0 \arrow[d]& \\
 & x(2x+1)=0 \arrow[dr,Leftarrow] \arrow[ddl,Leftarrow]& \\
 & & 2x+1=0 \arrow[d]\\
 x=0 & \lor & x=-\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with crossed out results.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\section*{With \texttt{forest}}
\[\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={edge+={thick,-stealth},math content,
if n children=0{tier=f}{}}
[{2x^2+x=0}
 [{x(2x+1)=0}
  [{x=0},cross out,draw=red]
  [{2x+1=0}
   [{x=-\frac{1}{2}}]
  ]
 ] 
]
\end{forest}\]

\section*{With \texttt{tikz-cd}}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={Leftrightarrow},column sep=0em]
 &  2x^2+x=0 \arrow[d]& \\
 & x(2x+1)=0 \arrow[dr,Leftarrow] \arrow[ddl,Leftarrow]& \\
 & & 2x+1=0 \arrow[d]\\
 |[cross out,draw=red]|x=0 & \lor & x=-\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I liked the tree. What is the meaning of `tier=f`?

Comment: @Sigur It ensures that `{x=0}` and `{x=-\frac{1}{2}}`are at the same level, i.e. at the same vertical position (for a tree growing south or north).

Comment: Interesting. Let me test without it.

Answer (score 4):

How about this layout, with `alignedat`? I replaced the underlining  with a coloured box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools, amssymb}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{cancel}
 \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{Crimson}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\colorboxed}[1]{\fcolorbox{Crimson}{Tomato!5}{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
 \xpatchcmd{\@Aboxed}{\boxed}{\colorboxed}{}{}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 & & 2x²+x &= 0 \\[-1.2ex]
  &\phantom{{}={}}\Updownarrow & & \\[-1.2ex]
  & & x(2x+1) &= 0 \\
     &\cancel{x= 0} & & &2 x+1 &=0\\
    & & & & \Aboxed{\enspace x &=-\mfrac{1}{2}\enspace }
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will do it, thank you!

Comment: What is questionable in the result (that you seem to have copied from the other answer)?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: It was questionable when I first posted. Since then, the question was edited, and I forgot to remove this sentence when I updated my answer. I'll fix it instantly.

Comment: I know it was questionable because I wrote it in the comment (before you wrote the answer...)

Comment: It seems once more that great minds think together… ;) I was probably typing while you were posting. In any case, I didn't look at what you wrote before posting. It was obvious to everyone there was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A mixture of `gather`, `gathered` and `aligned` provides you the alignment what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \begin{gathered}
    \begin{aligned}
        2 x^2 + x &= 0 \\
      x (2 x + 1) &= 0 \\
    \end{aligned}      \\
    \begin{aligned}
      \cancel{x = 0} & \qquad & 2 x + 1 &=  0 \\
                     &        &     2 x &= -1 \\
                     &        &       x &= -1/2
      \makebox[0pt][r]{\underline{\underline{\phantom{$x = -1/2$}}}}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{gathered}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```